# How to print the confidence level of a predicted image

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I trained a logistic regression model on the *mnist* data set, these are the important variables...

```
# tf Graph Input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) # mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes

# set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# construct model
logits = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)  # Softmax

# minimize error using cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))

# Gradient Descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Now what I did is I created an array called `adversarial` of slightly altered images that I feed back into the model so that it can make a prediction.

If I do the following...

```
classification_adversarial = sess.run(tf.argmax(pred, 1), feed_dict={x:adversarial})
print(classification_adversarial)

>> [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

I get an output of the model's prediction. This is the intended output, the model thinks that the images are 6s.

Anyways, for each of these images, I would like an `accuracy` to be displayed. So if I feed one image such as `adversarial.reshape((1, 784))`, I want the model to tell me how accurate, percentage-wise, is its prediction.

I tried to implement something like the following to get the total accuracy...

```
# list of booleans to determine the correct predictions
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), np.array([6]*10))
print(correct_prediction.eval({x:adversarial}))

>> [True, True ... , True, True]

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: adversarial}))

>> Accuracy: 1.0
```

I am getting an accuracy of `1.0`. What does this mean, my model is 100% accurate? If this is so, I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To print confidence of each image, you have to print "pred" which is softmax of logits.
2. In your case, accuracy is measured only for 10 images and model is correct in all 10 cases. So, accuracy is 1.0

Does that makes sense ?? Comment if you need more information.